# Use attribute of a derived class in parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to use `define_method` to create additional methods for classes inheriting from a superclass:

```
class Child < Parent
  ADDITIONAL_METHODS += ['xyz', 'qwe']
end

class Parent
  ADDITIONAL_METHODS = ['common']
  ADDITIONAL_METHODS.each do |key|
    define_method key do
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

This doesn't work because ADDITIONAL_METHODS is always taken from the Parent class and the only method created is `common`. Is there a way to access the attribute from the derived class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example code would not work, because you use `Parent` as ancestor of `Child` before declaring `Parent`.

This would produce this error :

```
uninitialized constant Parent (NameError)
```

If it actually works for you, it means that `Parent` has indeed be declared before `Child`. In that case, the `#each` loop on `ADDITIONAL_METHODS` is performed before `Child` even exists, since instructions you give in a class outside method definition are executed right away :

```
class Foo
  def initialize
    puts "second"
  end

  puts "first"
end

Foo.new
puts "third"
```

Outputs :

```
first
second
third
```

### Solution

You may want to implement a class method and call it right away, to perform that.

```
class Parent
  private

  def self.add_my_methods( *methods )
    ( methods.empty? ? [ 'common' ] : methods ).each do |key|
      define_method key do
        p key
      end
    end
  end

  add_my_methods # will implement "common"
end

class Child < Parent
  add_my_methods 'xyz', 'qwe'
end


c = Child.new
c.common # outputs "common"
c.xyz    # outputs "xyz"
c.qwe    # outputs #qwe"
```

This is an usual pattern for metaprogramming on descendants, like you probably already encountered it with methods like `#has_many`, `#before_filter`, etc.

Comment: Yeah, Child and Parent are in separate files, so Parent is defined first. Using a class method works nicely, thanks. But I'm wondering if it's possible to achieve the same effect without explicitly calling add_my_method. Is there a method that can loop over all derived classes?

Comment: It would be tricky for several reasons. First, there's not `#descendants` methods like there's an `#ancestors` one. You would have to loop on *all* runtime constants and check if they are descendant (which would be prohibitive, for performance reasons). Secondly, you would have to call this as a class method of Parent and call that method. Any child declared after that call would be ignored, which may cause hard to debug problems when classes are loaded on demand, like in development environment.

Comment: You could slightly reduce the perf problem if you namespace your childs, like `class Parent::Child < Parent`. That way, you can loop on them using `Parent.constants.select { |c| c.is_a? Parent }`. But that still ignore later declared/loaded childs.